# How to group the list based on values in scala?

Tags: java, scala

How to use group by in List of scala?
I am beginner In my code m getting some List of records and I want to just use group by in List. Here is my List example

```
 List((smith,swarm_4,group_2,400,1200), (smith,swarm_5,group_2,400,1200),
     (Michel,swarm_4,group_2,400,400), (smith,swarm_6,group_3,400,1200),    
     (smith,swarm_7,group_3,400,1200), (Michel,swarm_4,group_2,300,200), 
     (Michel,swarm_5,group_2,400,400), (Michel,swarm_6,group_3,400,400), 
     (Michel,swarm_7,group_3,400,400), (smith,swarm_5,group_2,100,200)
 )
```

Assume List contains records in this format (Name: String, swarm: String, group: String, Tx: Long, Rx: Long).
I want to group by (swarm and group) and group is match then aggregate (Tx+Tx)and (Rx + Rx).

eg:

```
 (smith,swarm_5,group_2,400,1200) and (smith,swarm_5,group_2,100,200) ==>
((swarm_5,group_2) => (400+100, 1200+200) => output(smith,swarm_5,group_2,500,1400))
```

so that output become like

```
  List((smith,swarm_4,group_2,400,1200), (smith,swarm_5,group_2,500,1400),
       (Michel,swarm_4,group_2,700,600), (smith,swarm_6,group_3,400,1200), 
       (smith,swarm_7,group_3,400,1200), (Michel,swarm_5,group_2,400,400), 
       (Michel,swarm_6,group_3,400,400), (Michel,swarm_7,group_3,400,400))
```

Please suggest me any idea to use group by or any other ideas in scala coding.

Comment: What have you already tried, and what problems did you ran into? See here for info on asking good questions: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

This code should work for your given list

```
var outList = inList.map( x =>  ((x._1,x._2,x._3),x._4,x._5)))
         .groupBy(_._1)
         .map{case (key,value) => 
                 value.reduce( (x,y) => (x._1,(x._2._1+y._2._1,x._2._2+y._2._2) ) )};
```